# pushing view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I want to have search functionality similar to that of the instagram app.
When editing begins in the search bar push a view controller and have the search bar filter that controller. However when I push a view controller, the navigation bar the search bar goes away and a back button is shown along with the new view.

Is it possible to

1. **push the view controller from the bottom of the screen**
2. **keep the search bar from disappearing**

Here's my `func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let resultsController = ResultsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Are you sure they push a view controller, as opposed to showing a part-sized view as an animated overlay?

Comment: Search bar coupled with view controller? Do you know about [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller)?

Comment: Pushing the view controller from the bottom is not the default behavior of push action. It's presenting modal behavior. Still if you want to do it, you can make a custom animation class and change animation of push

Comment: @matt does UISearchController show the search bar in the navigationbar?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I tried presenting a modal but it covers the navigation controller because it's full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest putting the search bar as part of a parent ViewController and toggling between two child view controllers whenever the search bar is in use. This code shows how to add a child view controller to a parent. There are similar methods to removing it. This way you can choose which view controller you want to show in different scenarios.

```
self.addChildViewController(searchVC)
self.scrollView.addSubview(searchVC.view)
searchVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Is it possible to animate the switch?

Comment: I believe you can just add an animation to the view of the child View Controller. Use this function - transitionFromViewController: toViewController:

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162874/swapping-child-views-in-a-container-view